# Accessing an instance method embedded in the monad stack

Tags: haskell

I have defined a newtype wrapper over a monad stack but struggling to work out how to implement an "already" implemented typeclass method. It feels like it should be easy to utilise the `gmask` method from `Ghc` in the `ExceptionMonad` instance for `EngineM` but I can't get my head around the necessary boilerplate and lifting to get it to work correctly. Any pointers?

```
newtype EngineM a = EngineM { _runEngineM :: RWST EngineEnv EngineLog EngineState Ghc a }

instance ExceptionMonad Ghc where ...
-- already implemented

instance ExceptionMonad EngineM where
  gmask :: ((m a -> m a) -> m b) -> m b
  gmask f = ??
```

Comment: Assuming that RWST has an instance for `ExceptionMonad`, then place `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` at the top of your module and write `newtype EngineM a = EngineM { ... } deriving (ExceptionMonad)`.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the exceptions package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make this easier by providing [orphan instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance) for `RWST` for the `Ghc` typeclasses `MonadIO` and `ExceptionMonad`. This fits into a general strategy for building interpreters from transformers - write classes for each property, implement how each transformer preserves that property, and derive the classes on the final transformer stack with

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

I'm going to prefix all of the imports from the [ghc API](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/libraries/ghc-7.8.3/index.html) with `Ghc` so I can keep them straight.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.RWS.Strict

import qualified Exception as Ghc
import qualified GhcMonad as Ghc
import qualified MonadUtils as Ghc
```

We'll keep your definition of `EngineM`, `deriving` the type classes we are interested in.

```
newtype EngineM a = EngineM { _runEngineM :: RWST EngineEnv EngineLog EngineState Ghc.Ghc a }
    deriving (Ghc.ExceptionMonad, Ghc.MonadIO, Monad, Applicative, Functor)
```

Making a `Ghc.MonadIO` instance for `RWST` is straightforward in terms of `lift` from `Control.Monad.Trans.Class`. We need this because `Ghc.MonadIO` is a superclass of `Ghc.ExceptionMonad`.

```
instance (Monoid w, Ghc.MonadIO m) => Ghc.MonadIO (RWST r w s m) where
    liftIO = lift . Ghc.liftIO
```

A `Ghc.ExceptionMonad` instance is trickier. You may have already noticed that `RWST` comes with a `liftCatch` function for lifting things like `Ghc.gcatch`. The majority of the problem is providing a `gmask` definition.

```
instance (Monoid w, Ghc.ExceptionMonad m) => Ghc.ExceptionMonad (RWST r w s m) where
    gcatch = liftCatch Ghc.gcatch
    gmask f = RWST $ \r s -> Ghc.gmask $ \restore -> runRWST (f (mapRWST restore)) r s
```

It's a bit difficult to explain, so first I'll write out all of the types involved

```
liftMask :: (((m   (a, s, w)  -> m    (a, s, w)) -> m    (b, s, w)) -> m    (b, s, w)) ->
             ((RWST r w s m a -> RWST r w s m a) -> RWST r w s m b) -> RWST r w s m b
liftMask mask f = RWST $ \r s -> mask $ \restore -> runRWST (f (mapRWST restore)) r s
```

The idea here is that, given a way to mask async errors in arbitrary computations `m a -> m a`, we have a value `m b`. The whole type of such a value is therefore `(m a -> m a) -> m b`. `gmask` needs to provide a way to mask async errors in arbitrary computations, and in doing so can convert a value that depends on that ability to simply an `m b`. This is why `gmask` has the convoluted type `((m a -> m a) -> m b) -> m b`.

Since the result of the computation must be an `m b`, or in our case an `RWST r w s m b`, we can start by returning the constructor for one. `RWST :: r -> s -> m (b, s, w) -> RWST r w s m b`. If we start writing a function definition here, it gives us an `r` and an `s` for later when we need them. The next thing we encounter is the `m` from `m (b, s, w)`, so we hand off the work to the underling `mask`. We now need to provide a function that, given a way to mask async errors, returns an `m (b, s, w)`. We'll call the way to mask async errors `restore`.  The only way we have to make the `b` that we need is stuck inside `f`, which expects a way to mask async errors with the type `RWST r w s m a -> RWST r w s m a` for all types `a`. `mapRWST` converts a function from `m (a, s, w) -> m (a, s, w)` into a function from `RWST r w s m a -> RWST r w s m a`, and `gmask` promised that `restore` is a way to mask async errors from `m a1 -> m a1` for all types `a1`, so `mapRWST restore` is exactly the way to mask async errors we need to pass to `f`. Now we are faced with the tiny problem that `f` returned an `RWST r w s m b` but we need an `m (b, s, w)`. `runRWST` will get us an `m (b, s, w)` from an `RWST r w s m b` if we have an `r` and an `s`. Fortunately we have an extra `r` and `s` sitting around from the outermost function, and we're done.